# How do I set the overflow to hidden to protect the elements go beyond my footer properly?

Tags: html, css, debugging, web

I'm having issues correctly using the `overflow` attribute. I am using the Boostrap sticky footer, and I am at a loss as to what to set to `overflow:hidden;` to prevent my page elements from breaking beyond the sticky footer on my page like so: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGs6u/)

I tried both setting the page's element container's `overflow` attribute to hidden, and the footer's (which I know is not the proper use case, but still.), to no avail.

My solution was to set all to overflow:hidden like so:

```
 * {
      overflow:hidden;
   }
```

however, this breaks other things that inherit the same style-sheet. Any input as to go about solving this would be excellent.

Any input as to how to go about doi

Comment: setting `overflow: hidden` for all elements isn't a good idea.

Comment: Did you try setting it on the `wrap` div?

Comment: I did to no noticeable changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overflow, Try this new css.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/eGs6u/2/

## CSS

```
#footer {
    border-top:solid 1px #fe2b32;
    background: rgba(254, 43, 50, 0.5);
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticky footers are tricky, and there are only a couple of methods that work, and they have to be followed exactly. You have some errors in your sticky footer setup that make it not work. Here's a stripped down version of your page with the fixes you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: -27px auto 0;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 27px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 80%;
}

#footer {
  height: 26px;
  border-top:solid 1px #fe2b32;
  background: rgba(254, 43, 50, 0.5);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
      <div class="container">
              container content
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              container content
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              container content
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              container content
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
University of Toronto &copy; 2013
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Put all of your content (apart from footer content) inside the `.container` div, and make sure that the content in the footer doesn't exceed 26px. For example, any `<p>` element in there must not have auto top/bottom margins on it. Otherwise the footer will blow out and the design will break. That's the limitation of sticky footer layouts: the footer has a fixed height.